# Is there a way I can make a method return something if a String is not formatted as a double

Tags: java, string, double, try-catch

I am working in java and I am making a static method that takes in a String that is a number (it must be a string because additional trailing 0s are important and they would be lost if I converted the input to a double right away). Is there a way I can check if this String can be converted to a double so I can stop the method if it cannot? I think it would be a try catch block around Double.parseDouble(myString); but I am not sure what the exception is called. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you should read the [JavaDocs for that method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html), or see what your compiler/IDE tells you when you.

Comment: "Java Double parse" in Google would have been faster than typing this question

Answer (score 1):

the exception thrown would be - `NumberFormatException`

You can refer the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Which you can learn from reading the JavaDoc for Double.parseDouble

Comment: Yes true..i have added a link to that as well

Comment: @user1943992 whenever in doubt consult the documentation first, try it out yourself and still if you have some confusion then ask on SO

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt the conversion inside a try catch, and then resolve the exception,

Or if you want to be more proactive (or if the string will not be a double more often than it is) then you'll want to do some kind of patten or regular expression matching; that's the usual way to do tests for strings.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html